# Kaltura inbuilt video streaming capabilities for HDS/HLS

Tags: video-streaming, wowza, http-live-streaming, kaltura

Does kaltura provided functionality to stream an Video file using HLS/HDS or any other streaming protocol?

OR we need to install/configure Wowza like streaming server with Kaltura setup to do the video streaming?

**Question is,** Does Kaltura has inbuilt streaming capabilities or we need third-party solutions?

If it has inbuilt capability for streaming using HLS/HDS etc, which server or technology it uses for the streaming?

Reason for this question is, We have Kaltura CE local setup and we are trying to archive HDS/HLS streaming using it, but somehow it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about VOD - we do provide open source vod packager for HLS/HDS/DASH/MSS.
https://github.com/kaltura/nginx-vod-module

Enjoy :-)

Comment: Yes my question is related to VOD files, so kaltura uses nginx for HLS/HDS/DASH for VOD streaming, is this right statement?

Comment: If I am not wrong `nginx` is just an web server, but my question is about converting an MP4 file to HLS/HDS/DASH. not about delivering the generated files. Does kaltura has inbuilt capabilities for converting to HLS/HDS protocol or we need to use Wowza type of media server which does this.

Comment: We have a module to nginx and this module do the segmentation for you - open source - you can use other streaming servers such as Wowza or AMS

Comment: So if I upload an MP4 file on Kaltura KMC, and from client side if I ask for HLS/HDS stream then kaltura should provide me HLS/HDS stream without using any third party tools. But some how this part is not working in the Kaltura CE setup that I have, I request for HLS stream but I only get master m3u8 file and then after when I request for TS segment then it is not found error I get. What may be the problem.

Comment: i suggest you post a question in the kaltura forum site - the developers will glad to help on that.

Comment: Added this question on Kaltura forum, I was planning to post this question on kaltura forum, but it is not that active forum so I posted it here.